# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join("branches","branches.id","users.branch_id")->get()

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

```
$query = \DB::table("public.users")->join("branches",function($join){$join->on("branches.id", "=", "users.branch_id");})->get;

dd($query());
```

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join("branches","branches.id","users.branch_id")->get()

Larvel show query result

Comment: the error seems not related to your query above. Show the full function code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to remove public from the query.
$query = \DB::table("users")->join("branches",function($join){$join-
```

> on("branches.id", "=", "users.branch_id");})->get;

Answer (score 0):

```php
$query = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->get();
```